# Classical Quantum or Relativistic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, relativity, kinetic-theory

An ensemble contains free electrons at 10^3 electrons per m^3 at 10^7 K. What can this ensemble be treated as: a Classical Quantum or Relativistic gas or in some overlapping domain?

Comment: Have you worked out the energy level spacings and compared them to $kT$? Have you compared $kT$ to the rest mass of an electron? This looks very like you're just trying to get us to do a homework problem for you.